# How do I make a scope to output a limited number of entries (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I bet this has a simple answer.. Let's say I have a Post model and I want to have a scope that returns the ten most recent entries. I thought I could write the scope like this:

```
   scope :first_ten order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
```

But this returns the error

```
 syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
     scope :first_ten order('created_at ASC').limit(10)
```

How do I write this scope correctly? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the comma which separates the two arguments being the name of the scope `:first_ten` and the arel-object `order('created_at ASC').limit(10)`

So i guess it should read 
 `scope :first_ten, order('created_at DESC').limit(10)`